# absolute positioned anchor does not render correctly when a phone number is detected in mobile safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-safari, jquery-masonry

I'm using the jquery masonry plugin which uses absolute positioning. Everything works fine until a masonry brick contains a phone number. Then the absolute positioning seems to be ignored, and the brick spans the full width of the page and positions at the top.

This affects only the brick that contains the phone number. All other bricks are rendered normally.

This can be fixed by adding:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

But this disables the phone number recognition functionality of the mobile safari browser.

Has anyone experienced something similar or knows a solution?

Comment: Does it work if you turn off the auto-detection, but use [the tel: URL scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html) to put a phone link in manually? (I'm guessing that still breaks, but it's worth checking...)

Comment: @Matt Gibson: This is not possible in my use case. The bricks are integrated in a of CMS and all inputted html is escaped.